# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (28) into shape (28,0) on adding array to another

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to add a numpy array to another numpy array, but I'm getting this error:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (28) into shape (28,0)
```

This is my code:

```
sample = np.fabs(sample - avg)
counter = np.arange(1,len(sample)+1)
np.append(sample, counter, axis=1)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: For a start drop the `as_matrix` method.  But where's the problem?  In the `sample-avg` part?  If so what's the source and shape of those 2 variables.?  An array of shape `(28,0)` is suspicious. It's empty.

Comment: I edited my code. the problem is on the third line, on append the column to another one.

Comment: Stay away from `array.append`.  People often misuse it.  List append is better, or `concatenate` with all its warts.

Comment: @hpaulj how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This indicates that the array with shape (28,0) is in fact empty, which means you might need to address your upstream processing that generated sample and avg, and verify the contents of these objects. I could replicate this with the following:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import random
a = random.rand(28)
b = random.random((28,0))
print(a.shape, b.shape)
```

(28,) (28, 0)

```
print(a + b)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-f1c1de818ef8> in <module>()
      5 print(a.shape, b.shape)
      6 
----> 7 print(a + b)
      8 
      9 print(b)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (28,) (28,0)

print(b)
```

[]